# Copy values of a database and adjust their datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to create new table rows. I take an entry from my original table and copy this item into a new row. But the DateTime value is always increased by one month. I want to loop every item in my entry item table.

My original table:

```
ID  MyDateTime
1   2018-07-22 11:38:23.123
2   2018-07-22 11:39:23.123
```

My expected result:

```
ID  MyDateTime
1   2018-07-22 11:38:23.123
2   2018-07-22 11:39:23.123
3   2018-08-22 11:38:23.123
4   2018-08-22 11:39:23.123
```

Here is what I have until now but I stuck: https://pastebin.com/CjhAJ49Q

Comment: It looks like the `id` is also incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change table, then use `insert`:

```
insert into t (MyDateTime)
    select dateadd(month, 1, MyDateTime)
    from t
    order by MyDateTime;
```

If you simply want a query that produces the results, then:

```
select row_number() over (order by MyDateTime) as id,
       MyDateTime
from ((select MyDateTime from t) union all
      (select dateadd(month, 1, MyDateTime) from t
     ) t
order by MyDateTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server you could do something like this to add year to dates:

```
select DATEADD(year, 1, MyDateTime) from originalTable
```

So select all rows from originalTable, union them with query above and insert all rows to destinationTable:

```
insert into destinationTable
select MyDateTime from originalTable
union all
select DATEADD(year, 1, MyDateTime) from originalTable
```

Comment: Change `year` to `month` to address the specific question.